# I have issues of printing out the string correctly

Tags: python, string, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I wanted the code to print out certain strings.
The issue was the the output was not what I expected, since it would print out something like this:
BruhBruh
BruhBruh

I was hoping for this:
Bruh
Bruh

How do I fix it?

```
def repeate(c,rep):
  c=input("what str")
  rep=int(input("how many times?"))
  for i in range(rep):
    print(c*rep)
  return i

repeat=repeate(0,0)
print(repeat)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a space to the user input.

Change your line:
c=input("what str") + “ “

Now if the user enters “Dude”, c will be “Dude “.

Answer (score 0):

by calling `print(c*rep)` you are printing out a catenation of `rep` instances of string `c`
and this gets repeated in cycle `for i in range(rep):` for additional `rep` times

to get string repeated certain amount of times you may use function `join` on the array of strings, e.g.

```
print(" ".join(['Bruh']*3))
```

alternately use print with default (crlf) terminator replaced with space char:

```
for i in range(3):
    print("Bruh", end=" ")
```

also, both args of this function are useless -- you just set them in function body via `input`